# Dropdown menu overlaid by the content

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, dropdown

The current theme of my WordPress website has two menus, a top menu and a bottom menu

The dropdown menu of the bottom menu are overlaid by the above content for example

I tried to perform the setup of the z-index, putting z-index: 20000 for example, but it didn't work for example

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix it?

**My WordPress website:** [www.rodrigocorrea.org](https://rodrigocorrea.org/)

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 43.75em)
.menu-footer-items .sub-menu:hover {
    bottom: 24px;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

@media (min-width: 43.75em)
.menu-footer-items .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    background: #1A1A1A;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 220px;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    bottom: -9999px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
    transform: scale(0.95);
}

.menu-footer-items ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Please update an image on the problem here so we can know what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Instead of having a separate navigation that is the same as the one in your header, why not make your header navigation sticky on scroll, so that the menu is always there for the user to interact with? Might be the better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove overflow from footer:
Set custom css:

```
footer.site-footer {
    overflow: initial !important;
}
```